# Getting the size of my array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to get the size of my array but am having no luck...
I've read from various other threads that the way to grab the size of an array is:
    theSize = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

But that seems to grab the empty elements of the array too.

How would we grab just the elements that are used up... for example:

```
char array[200][40];

for (i = 1; i < (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])); i++) {
    printf("%s", array[i-1]);
```

The  output for an array that used 3 of its 200 elements would be...

```
First 
Second
Third
(This is where it should stop, however it gives a bunch of question marks, 
so I assume I'm grabbing memory i'm not supposed to use.
```

*Note: I want it so that i < 3  for the loop (since the array has 3 elements used up)*

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use, `sizeof()` is only about its total size in memory.

Comment: Oh, I see, would there be any other way to do what I need?

Comment: you have to maintain your own size varable

Comment: Well, usually the last element is somehow flagged as being the last. The same way the end of a string carries the symbol `\x00` representing it ends there, you can detect the end of your list by testing if the string you are analyzing is of `strlen(array[i-1]) == 0` (an empty string)

Comment: Or you could simply keep track of how many elements you are actually using.

Comment: Who else thought they were offering me a "<3" heart at the bottom of their question? :(

Comment: A C array is something of a fiction, and does not maintain any "size" information with it at runtime.  You must separately keep track of its size somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

- The first way is to keep track of how many elements are used in a separate variable. Note that you must ensure that `used` is always less than of equal to the size of the array.

  ```
  char array[200][40];
  size_t used = 3;
  for (int i = 0; i < used; ++i) {
      printf("%s", array[i]);
  }
  ```
- The second way is to flag the first unused element with a special value, such as 0, and output all values until the flagged one. In your case, it would be natural to mark the end of the array with an empty string.

  ```
  char array[200][40];
  size_t size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < size && array[i][0] != 0; ++i) {
      printf("%s", array[i]);
  }
  ```